# prorotobuf-net for DotNet Core?

Tags: protobuf-net

I've finally decided to see what happens if I try to migrate my (large) project to DotNet Core 2.1.  Got as far as protobuf-net.  As near as I can tell, the NuGet package (v2.3.11) tries to bring in .NET 4.0.  I'm a little confused, because a quick Google search makes it sound like some folks are using protobuf-net with DotNet Core.

The project website (https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) says that the preferred support channel is an SO question tagged with protobuf-net.  So, here ya go: Is there an easy way to bring protobuf-net into my DotNet Core project without bringing inn a bunch of standard .NET stuff (short of cloning the project and trying to build it myself against DotNetCore)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: it already fully supports .NET Core, and you shouldn't have to do anything except add a package reference (presumably from nuget.org).

Longer version:

.NET Core is two different things:

- .NET Standard (the shared target standard, which is implemented by multiple platforms)
- .NET Core App (the new .NET core platform)

The package on nuget includes targets for .NET Standard, meaning it can run on *many many* platforms that are aware of .NET Core, including .NET Core App (which implements .NET Standard). There are currently targets for .NET Standard 1.0 (down-level platforms), .NET Standard 1.3 (everything else 1.*) and .NET Standard 2.0 (everything 2.*). We will probably also add a .NET Core App 2.1 target soon, to allow some specific 2.1 platform features.

Note that you can see the target platforms by expanding the "Dependencies" tab on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net

[image]

Comment: Curious minds want to know: Why, when I install this in a DotNet Core 2.1 project, does it tell me that it is installing a zillion DLLs that appear to be coming from .NET 4.x?  Is that something in the way the NuGet package is built?

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health clarify please: netstandard, or netcoreapp?

Comment: Steps to repro: In VS 2017, with the DotNet Core 2.1 SDK installed, create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application. On the 2nd page of the wizard, select Web Application.  Build the project. Manage NuGet Packages, browse for protobuf-net. It finds V2.3.12.  Install that.  Curiously, as I'm reproducing this right now, the only thing it wants to touch in addition to installing protobuf-net.2.3.12 is System.Reflection.TypeExceptions.4.3.0 -> System.Reflection.TypeExceptions.4.4.0.  When I did this a few days ago on my production app, it gave me a list of 20+ such items.

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health sounds like everything working normally... not sure there's anything I can investigate there, especially if it only wants one thing now. It might be because your cache is now populated, of course. But: not sure there's anything for me to be concerned about here...

Comment: Can you educate me (and others who may stumble upon this). All of the other installers I've dealt with only claim to be installing their software.  But your installer wants to pull in bits with 4.x version numbers. That smells to me like I'm pulling in .NET 4.x stuff, not DotNet Core (or Standard or whatever) stuff. What's that all about?

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health a: I haven't written an installer - heck, I didn't even write the nuspec - it uses standard "dotnet" pack tools; b: I haven't yet seen the thing you're reporting; it *could* simply be downstream requirements of the IL-emit stuff; that's hard to opine on, as they've done very nasty things to that package - including now hiding it from view completely.

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health oh, are you talking about the popup window? in that, it tells you about dependencies of **all** possible targets, not just the target you're using

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, it appears that protobuf-net really does support DotNet Core. Following the instruction in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps), I installed NuGet Package Explorer, which tells me that protobuf-net include netstandard2.0. The naming is confusing, but, according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), DotNet Core 2.0 implements .Net Standard 2.0.